# Variants / Iterating / VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variant

I am trying to access elements of a variant that I am creating via ranges on an Excel sheet. The number of rows in my range is dynamic based on the number of rows on the "Locations" sheet, so I simply declare a variant, and then set it equal to the relevant range. I use the 4 variables prefixed with Loc to find the boundaries and set the variant once I have created that final range.

However, I'm unable to iterate through numerous attempts. I am sure I am missing something fundamental, but have yet to make the For Each or For LBound/UBound structures work for array iteration. The variant data is a mixture of numbers and text.

Your thoughts on the easy/simple thing that I am sure I am missing are appreciated. I understand that for each is read-only and would prefer to read/write, but for now simply want to make sure I can iterate at all through this array [really, a matrix]

```
Sub Prefill_Work_Sub()
    ' Variables
    Dim LocRowStart As Range
    Dim LocRowEnd As Range
    Dim LocSheetRange As Range
    Dim EndColInt As Integer
    Dim LocationsVariant As Variant

    ' Ending Column Index Set
    EndColInt = 72

    ' First, make range of location sheet
    Set LocRowStart = Worksheets("Locations").Range("A2")
    Set LocRowEnd = Worksheets("Locations").Cells(Rows.Count, LocRowStart.Column).End(xlUp)
    Set LocColEnd = Worksheets("Locations").Cells(LocRowEnd.row, EndColInt)
    Set LocSheetRange = Worksheets("Locations").Range(LocRowStart, LocColEnd)
    Set LocationsVariant = LocSheetRange


    ' Verify the range address of the variant
    ' Debug.Print LocSheetRange.Address

    For i = LBound(LocationsVariant) To UBound(LocationsVariant)
        Debug.Print LocationsVariant(i, 1)
    Next i

    ' Let's try to iterate through variant for a sec
    ' Debug.Print LocationsVariant(1, 1)
    ' Debug.Print LocationsVariant(2, 1)


End Sub
```

Comment: You have not set a value for `LocationsVariant`.  Did you mean to assign a range's value to that ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I just edited and added that line. It was there in my code but accidentally deleted in post. So, I run into a type mismatch error once I hit the line with lbound() / ubound()

Comment: Don't use `Set` when assigning the value if you want to get a 2D array.  Otherwise you're creating another Range-type variable

Comment: @TimWilliams Doh, thank you. If only I had tried that... Appreciate the help.

Comment: Also dont forget to iterate on the two dimensions of your array of values.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `LocColEnd` equal to a range and then passing it as the column number argument to the range function in the next line.  But the column number argument needs to be an integer.

```
Set LocColEnd = Worksheets("Locations").Cells(LocRowEnd.row, EndColInt)
Set LocSheetRange = Worksheets("Locations").Range(LocRowStart, LocColEnd)
```

You have a few options to correct this.  The best would probably be to just use `EndColInt` as the column number argument like so:

```
Set LocSheetRange = Worksheets("Locations").Range(LocRowStart, EndColInt)
```

This line also looks suspect.  I would recommend appending the Row property to the end like so:

```
LocRowEnd = Worksheets("Locations").Cells(Rows.Count, LocRowStart.Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Edited the above code to remove the Set keyword on the last line.